# calculating areas of polygons in R in a for loop

Tags: r, polygons, surface

Dear people of stackoverflow.

I am trying to calculate the area of each separate polygon of a SPDF. I am trying to make a function of it which allows me to put the data in and get a list of areas out. I am stuck with creating a for loop that returns all areas of my polygons. For the surface calculation of one polygon the following code works:

```
surfacefirstpolygon <- gArea(inputSPDF[1,1])
```

This code prints the i's one by one when I run the following code.

```
polys <- slot(inputSPDF,"polygons")
for(i in 1:length(polys)){
  print(i)
}
```

Then I try to put these pieces of code together in a for loop by doing the following:

```
polys <- slot(inputSPDF,"polygons")
areasofpolygons <- for(i in 1:length(polys)){
  gArea(inputSPDF[i,i])
}
```

This does not work and gives me the following error.

Error in is.projected(spgeom) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'is.projected': Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected.

Anybody know what is going wrong?

Result =

```
dd = dim(inputSPDF) 
for(i in 1:dd[1]){ 
   areasofpolygons[i] <- gArea(inputSPDF[i,1]) 
}
```

Comment: I figured it might be because list is not able in putting them underneath each other. So I tried the following which also does not work:
    test <- list() 
    for(i in 1:length(polys)){ 
       test[i] <- gArea(gem_ned_LAEA[i,i]) 
    }

Comment: What is `data` and `gArea`? This is not reproducible! BTW: There is no list comprehension mechanism in R in that way you try to do. Have a look at the [apply functions](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) to realize such things.

Comment: data is my input data and gArea is a function of the package rgeos which calculates the surface of a polygon. Thank you for the apply link. Will look at it now.

Regarding the reproducibility: I am working with an SpatialPolygonDataFrame. It is not that easy to produce one from scratch. In another question that I asked, I linked my script to dropbox and let people download my shapefile from my dropbox. Then I got the comment that this could be unsafe. I do not know how to make it a better reproducible script.

Comment: What is the output of dim(inputSPDF) just before the 'for' loop?

Comment: Unfortunately your answer below is returning an empty areasofpolygons. When I run the following code: - dd = dim(inputdata) - Running dd returns: [1] 510 58

Comment: So if i is going beyond 58, an error will be there. Try my answer below and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dd = dim(inputSPDF)
for(i in 1:dd[1]) for(j in 1:dd[2]){
      areasofpolygons[length(areasofpolygons)+1] = gArea(inputSPDF[i,j])
    }
areasofpolygons
```

The error mentioned in the question probably indicates that i is exceeding the dimensions ("undefined columns selected"). Also, only identical row and column numbers will be accessed if [i,i] is used.

Comment: To make it a good answer, please add some comments on what this code does and how.

Comment: I have added some information. Feedback from @Zuenie will also be appreciated.

Comment: When I run these lines it runs pretty long (like 5 minutes) and then returns an empty areasofpolygons. It returns no error. But thank you already for helping me! I do not comprehend why the number of columns would be wrong also in my first script.

Comment: Your loop is not alloting the result. I have edited my code above. Try and let us know the result.

Comment: got it! Delete the j part and include areasofpolygons in the formula and it works. So firstline: dd = dim(inputSPDF)
secondline:  for(i in 1:dd[1]){
      areasofpolygons[i] <- gArea(inputSPDF[i,1])
    }

Comment: Your code actually is not giving the right result. It inspired me to come to my right answer so I accepted it as the right answer. When running your code I get more areas than I have polygons. And it takes a long time compared to my line which I added in the question under result. Thank you very much for helping me!